# Oracle: LONG RAW to BLOB - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to convert a LONG RAW value into a BLOB one and I'm getting an error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY, got LONG BINARY.
Code sample(document is a LONG RAW column):

```
DECLARE 
  var_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
  select To_Blob(document) into var_blob
    from instructions
    where id = 'XXX';
END;
```

I get the same error if I try to execute the code as a simple SQL query (without the PL/SQL code).
What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Using the information from the answers I tried doing:

```
create table temp_blob(id VARCHAR2(50), file_contents blob);
```

and then:

```
DECLARE
  z_id varchar(50) := 'XXX';
  z_blob blob;
BEGIN
 execute immediate '
  insert into temp_blob
  select :z_id, To_Blob(document)
   from instructions
   where id = :z_id' using z_id, z_id;

 begin
   select file_contents into z_blob
   from temp_blob where id = z_id;
 end;
END;
```

I'm still getting the same error. Also some additional information - the size of the result of the query:

```
select document
from instructions
where id = 'XXX';
```

is bigger than 32760 bytes, so I cannot assign it to a PL/SQL variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get answer from Tom Kyte's blog. He's already answered [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:13213885403654)

**Edited:**

We should use TO_LOB instead of TO_BLOB.

Let's check it out:

- create two tables :

  ```
  create table instructions (id varchar2(50), document long raw);
  create table temp_blob(id VARCHAR2(50), file_contents blob);
  ```
- populate INSTRUCTIONS with data that exceeds 32767 bytes (to be sure that no implicit conversion to pl/sql varchar2 occurs) in DOCUMENT column. For this purpose I use this small solution (in C#):

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Data;
  using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

  namespace LongRaw
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("Data Source=XE;User ID=<user_name>;Password=<user_pass>;Pooling=yes;"))
              {
                  connection.Open();
                  using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("insert into instructions values (:id, :document)", connection))
                  {
                      Random random = new Random();
                      byte[] document = new byte[65535];

                      random.NextBytes(document);

                      command.Parameters.Add("id", "XXX");
                      command.Parameters.Add("document", OracleDbType.LongRaw, 65535, val: document, dir: ParameterDirection.Input);
                      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  }

                  connection.Close();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- now we have data in INSTRUCTIONS and execute our pl/sql-block:

  ```
  SQL> set echo on
  SQL> set serveroutput on
  SQL> 
  declare
      z_id varchar(50) := 'XXX';
      z_blob blob;
  begin
      execute immediate
      'insert into temp_blob
       select :z_id, to_lob(document)
       from   instructions
       where  id = :z_id' using z_id, z_id;
       select file_contents into z_blob
       from temp_blob where id = z_id;
       dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.getlength(z_blob) || ' bytes');
  end;
  /
  65535 bytes
  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

  SQL>
  ```
- And here we are - our z_blob contains 65535 bytes :)

Answer (score 0):

I tough nut to crack, but got a working code.

```
declare
l_long_row long raw := rpad( 'a', 2000, 'a' );
l_blob blob;
l_id number;
begin

execute immediate 'select
1,
TO_BLOB(:l_long_row)
into 
:l_id,
:l_blob
from dual'
into l_id, l_blob
using l_long_row;

insert into test_blob
(select
1,
l_blob
from dual);
end;
```

where table test_blob has attributes ID(number) and BIGBLOB(BLOB);

Hope it helps.